# iOS 8 Phonegap 2.9.0 issue on Media API

Tags: cordova, audio, media, decode, ios8

I don't know if someone has faced the same issue, but while the debugging of my app on the new iOS 8, I faced a problem with the Media API of phonegap.
In some of my audios which are less than 2 secs, the media api doesn't call the onStatus function, in order to update the status of the MediaPlayer at the end of the file. Instead it throws me an error "MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_DECODE", which means that something goes wrong with the file and its decode. I'm using phonegap 2.9.0 but I think that maybe this is an issue to the next versions too.
Does anyone has such a problem?
I hope to fix this at the final release of iOS 8, because now (iOS6 & iOS7) I don't face any similar problems.

Thank you all,

Comment: Have you tried a more recent PhoneGap? 2.9 is pretty old.

Comment: 2.9.0 was released back in June 2013, when iOS 6.x was still the norm.   As @RaymondCamden mentioned, I strongly suggest you update to the latest Cordova for full support. Note, iOS 8 is still in beta, the latest Cordova might still not be fully compatible.

Comment: Actually, today I deployed my app on Cordova 3.5.0, which is the latest version and I noticed the same issue. When the audio file is small, about 1-2 secs or less then the (Cordova)Media API returns MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_DECODE..On bigger files, more than 20 secs, there is no problem. I hope to be fixed on the final release of iOS 8.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  iOS 8 GM and cordova 3.5, the media api plays no sound.

Comment: WootWoot: Are you sure about that, because on my apps, the Media API plays just fine large audios(bigger than 2 secs). On the others audios, still exists the same error, but I fixed it, by releasing the Media object on the onError callback and then instanciate a new one. The strange thing is that on iOS6 & 7, there was not such a problem..What did they change???

Comment: I am facing a similar issue with different response. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324059/audio-not-playing-in-cordova-ios-8