# Audio not playing in Cordova iOS 8

Tags: ios, cordova, ios8

I am unable to play audio in iOS 8 Cordova app. the same code works on iOS 7.

The message I get is,

> Unknown resource 'documents://audioFilePath'

My Cordova version is 3.5.1 and Media plugin version is 0.2.15

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show some code of how do you use media plugin?

Comment: @Emre I call it as, myMedia = new Media("documents://../appName.app/www/" + src, function(){  this.release(); }); myMedia.play({"numberOfLoops": 2});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved This.

I was Creating the media object as,

```
new Media("documents://../appName.app/www/" + src...)
```

I Found that the resource pointer in iOS is always at www folder. So i just had to create the object as,

```
new Media("" + src...)
```